# How do I take the value of one batch file to another?

Tags: batch-file

Key Generator

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR A
ECHO Generating Key!
choice /d y /t 3 > nul
set /p "genkey"="%random%-%random%-%random%-%random%"
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Batch 2

```
COLOR A
@ECHO OFF
set /p base=
if %base% == %genkey% GOTO :ecs
:ecs
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: so how are these files named? And what exactly is your question? Which value do you want to take from which file to which other?

Comment: From `Key Generator.bat` you can use `Call "Batch 2.bat" "%genkey%"` and in `Batch 2.bat` you can change your `If` statement to `If /I Not "%base%"=="%~1" GoTo :EOF`

Comment: Can you change it?

Comment: Why are you using `SET /P` in the first batch file?  Looks like you want to just use a normal `SET` command.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask]. Kudos for MCVE, you can [edit] your own questions by clicking on the grey `edit` link below the tags at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 0):

The way I normally do this is by writing to a file and using SET to recall from the file.

For example:

BATCH FILE 1

```
echo off
set var1=%Random%-%Random%-%Random%
echo %var1%>temp.log
pause
exit
```

BATCH FILE 2

```
echo off
set Var1=nul
if EXIST Temp.log (set /p Var1=<Temp.log && del /Q Temp.log)
echo %Var1%
pause
exit
```

In this case, if you run the second batch file without running the first one, the output will be "nul". However, if you ran the first batch file before the seccond, the output of the first will be displayed.
You can change  `%Random%-%Random%-%Random%`  to whatever text or variable you want.
The program acts like the  `type`  function, however with this method it prints the contents of the file to a variable.

One last thing to note is that this method will ONLY read the first line of the file. This is useful where you are transfering numbers, then using that number in an operation. If you want to transfer the whole file, you can use a  `FOR`  state ment, but also note, the  `FOR`  statement will recall the entire into a singe line.